# Google oauth & apis how to do it

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-calendar-api

I can't find any documentation on using google oauth and google apis which I understand. At the moment, I am doing this, but it is not a complete guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

What I am trying to do:

I have a node based app, with a simple JS frontend.

- It needs a google login.
- When a user logs in, it creates a username for them on my server.
- It stores some google token somehow under this user on my server.
- Somehow give a `service` level access to my backend.
- This backend can then make changes and read calendar info whenever needed, without user interaction.

At the moment I have a google login which returns an auth code like this: `localhost:8000/?code=123`. I don't know what to do with that auth code. Documentation is only provided for `Java` and `Python` unfortunately.

The next thing is to get the auth tokens (somehow) then figure out how to give my `service account` access.

Anyone know how?

Comment: There is a couple of good library for OAuth and OpenID connect at https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js and https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS. Regardless of the library, the idea is the same. A simple explaination is at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org)? It has a very solid implementation for [Google](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth)

I have done something similar for Facebook and will paste it here in case it helps:

So firstly, I added the below into my node app:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
```

Then, the below:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Then, the below:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    userModel.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
clientID: config.facebook.appID,
clientSecret: config.facebook.appSecret,
callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'emails', 'birthday', 'location', 'bio', 'likes.limit(100)']
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
    //Do whatever I want
}
)
);
```

I won't explain all this but - see if it helps you with your Google apps integration. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah that was actually the first thing I tried. I couldn't get it working though. Does that one do google api access? Got pretty stuck because none of these strategies have any documentation.

Comment: I will edit my comment to add more info (but for Facebook) but it will give you an idea.